# How to run tests outside of integration folder in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I have project B linked to project A with `npm link` and am trying to run tests from B in A. Project A builds the entire front end and could use other modules than just B and so I want to be able have the test runner use A and its tests but also use tests from the linked project (assuming the linked projects all use similar Cypress directory structures). I first tried this by setting the `testFiles` attribute in the config to an array like `[/path/to/ProjectATestingRoot/integration/**/*.*", "/path/to/ProjectBTestingRoot/integration/**/*.*"]`
and running Cypress with `integrationFolder` to be from project A. While I'm able to see all my tests when I open Cypress, only project A's tests can be run. When I run project B's they get stuck when the browser loads the test and displays the "Your tests are loading..." screen for eternity.

Is there any way that I could run tests from outside the set integration folder? I thought I could write a little plugin to copy the testing files over but that seems more laborious than needed.

Answer (score 1):

Using [spec](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line#How-to-run-commands) should solve the problem

```
npx cypress run --spec [abloluteFolderPath}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>   "testFiles": "**/*.{feature,spec.tsx}",
>   "integrationFolder": ".",
>   "ignoreTestFiles": "**/node_modules/**/*{feature,spec.js}"
> ```

Add this to your `cypress.json`. It adds all the files with `.spec.tsx` ignoring the ones inside the node_module.

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/unit-testing__application-code

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options

1 You can specify `integrationFolder` in the `cypress.json`

```
 {
      //....
      "integrationFolder": "cypress/tests"
      // or
      // "integrationFolder": "tests"
      
  }
```

More information https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Folders-Files

2 You can specify integration folder for each test run

```
npx cypress --config integrationFolder=cypress/tests
npx cypress --config integrationFolder=tests
```

More information https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2256#issuecomment-544408366

Comment: `"integrationFolder": "."` is a bad idea, it scans node_modules, picks up unnecessary tests and takes forever to load.